# Unable to load dynamic library(DYLIB) in MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, dllimport, dylib, dlopen

I am trying to load a library(say **ArithmeticOprn.dylib**) dynamically and call the methods presented within that library. Please refer to the sample code snippet from below,

```
[DllImport("libdl.dylib")]
public static extern IntPtr dlopen(String fileName, int flags);

[DllImport("ArithmeticOprn.dylib")]
public static extern double Add(double a, double b);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dlopen("path/to/ArithmeticOprn.dylib", 2);
    double result = Add(1, 2);
}
```

While running the above sample in MacOS, I got the following exception:

> **Unable to load DLL "ArithmeticOprn.dylib": The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.**

But, when I provide full path in the DllImport the method call works and I can get the expected results. For your reference, please refer below for the code snippet.

```
[DllImport("path/to/ArithmeticOprn.dylib")]
public static extern double Add(double a, double b);
```

Could you please let me know what I am missing ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Similar questions found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036457/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-image-mac-os-x
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577127/unable-to-load-mac-os-x-dynamic-library-dylib-in-windows-exception-in-thread

Comment: @Kumar There's no answer found in it.

Comment: Yes. That's why added +1

Comment: @Kumar - yes he is right no answer is found.

Comment: What language is this? C#?

Comment: Yes, it is C# @Siguza

Comment: You should run `otool -L` (this is the (kind of) *OSX*s equivalent for *ldd*) on your lib, and check which dependencies are not found and why. Could be that they are present, but they target a different architecture.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late but I recently ran into similar issue myself and maybe that will save some time for others looking for answers.

It is good to have in mind what @CristiFati suggested in the comment - the lib in general might have targeted different arch, but as you said it is loading when given a full path so I think the arch is correct.

It would be interesting to know whether you use *Xamarin.Mac* or raw *mono* to run your application as they link libraries differently.

For *Xamarin.Mac* I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62197276/how-to-resolve-dllnotfoundexception-in-visual-studio-for-mac#62197276) - you should use

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <BundleResource Include="<path-to>ArithmeticOprn.dylib" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

in your *.csproj - it will add this native lib to the mono bundle created in process of compilation.

Where is for *mono* you would either need to:

1. do what @Petesh suggested in the answer above
2. create a symbolic link before running the app, like:

   `ln -sf ArithmeticOprn.dylib <path-to>ArithmeticOprn.dylib`
3. add `app.config` to your project which would do similar thing what 2) does, like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <configuration>
      <dllmap os="osx" dll="ArithmeticOprn.dylib" target="path/to/ArithmeticOprn.dylib"/>
    </configuration>
```

Hope that might help anyone being in pickle like me, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to short-cut the `DllImport` behaviour through an explicit `dlopen` - i.e. using the `dlopen` to specify the path that's supposed to be used by the `DllImport`. The problem is that the `DllImport` link-up is done internally to the `C#` run-time before the `dlopen` gets called.

the `dlopen` never gets a look in.

In order to use `DllImport` *without* a path, you need to rely on the default search behaviour, which is locations as specified by the environment variables `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, current working directory, `$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`.

So, for example:

```
env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/ mono test.exe
```

which runs the mono interpreter with the path pre-loaded with `path/to`, allowing it to find the `dylib` in that location.

Other solutions include moving the library into the directory with the executable, making a symlink to the library in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently stuck with this problem. I solved it by adding my **.dylib** file in *Targets* > *Build Phases* > *Embed Frameworks* (it works on simulator, I am not able to make it work on ios device though)

[image: imported lib5.dylib]

and then importing it like -

```
[DllImport("lib5.dylib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern int test(string s);
```