# How to resolve DLLNotFoundException in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: .net-core, dll, visual-studio-mac

I am new C#, and I am coming from C++. I have a simple project that should create an SFML Window and displays it.

```cs
using System;
using SFML.Graphics;

namespace SFMLGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RenderWindow window = (RenderWindow)sender;
            window.Close();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            SFML.Graphics.RenderWindow window = new SFML.Graphics.RenderWindow(new SFML.Window.VideoMode(800, 500), "Hello, World!");
            window.Closed += new EventHandler(OnClose);

            while (window.IsOpen)
            {
                window.Display();
                window.Clear(SFML.Graphics.Color.Magenta);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have installed the CSFML and SFML libraries using Homebrew.

I have added an `app.conf`, as specified, file to my project directory containing the DLL maps.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="csfml-system" target="libcsfml-system.dylib" />
    <dllmap dll="csfml-window" target="libcsfml-window.dylib" />
    <dllmap dll="csfml-graphics" target="libcsfml-graphics.dylib" />
    <dllmap dll="csfml-audio" target="libcsfml-audio.dylib" />
    <dllmap dll="csfml-network" target="libcsfml-newtork.dylib" />
</configuration>
```

However, I still get this:
`"Unable to load shared library 'csfml-graphics' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libcsfml-graphics, 1): image not found";`

Again I am new to C#, Visual Studio for Mac, and .NET in general.

Comment: Then what kind of project did you create? `app.config` won't work in a .NET Core console project.

Comment: Oh, I created a console project. Again I am new to Visual Studio for Mac and and the documentation said that only UWP apps didn't use app.config.

Comment: Please show a screen shot of the template you used to create that project. What you didn't know is that there are at least two different console project types. The documentation is rather harsh, and lacks much more information.

Comment: After you said I found out there is a console project and console application, I created a console application. [Image:](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnsVMEDPPDLBibgSXhuYmJIjmMDXnw?e=3bMMbX)

Comment: OK, so you does create a .NET Core console project. That's exactly why `app.config` won't work. You might try to follow the official guide to install native dependencies to your Mac system, https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php#installing-sfml If that does not help, ask the developers for more guidance, https://github.com/SFML/SFML.Net/issues

Comment: It looks like you are using Xamarin.Mac for compilation.
I think you might need to add
      <ItemGroup>
        <BundleResource Include="<path>libcsfml-graphics.dylib" />
(...)
      </ItemGroup>
to your .csproj
Or you could convert your project to run via raw mono which then would make your app.config work :)